# Convert json to a string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a nested json. I want to post it as a form input value.

But, seems like jquery puts `"Object object"` string into the value.

It seems easier to pass around the string and convert into the native form I need, than dealing with json as I don't need to change anything once it is generated.

#### What is the simplest way to convert a json

```
var json = {
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address": {
     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY",
     "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber": [
     { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
     { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
     ],
     "newSubscription": false,
     "companyName": null
 };
```

into its string form?

```
var json = '{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "address": {
     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY",
     "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber": [
     { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
     { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
     ],
     "newSubscription": false,
     "companyName": null
 }'
```

Following doesn't do what I need:

```
Json.stringify()
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: "Following doesn't do what I need:" -> How so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a method for JSON stringifying native objects.  You will need [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) which will provide the `JSON.stringify()` method to browsers that don't already support it.